# How to get cookie value in jquery which is set from C# class?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, cookies

I have created and set the cookie through C# class and I want to use this cookie value in jquery file.

Like I have created and set cookie ...

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("LoggedUserId");
myCookie.Value = newUser.UserId.ToString();
```

and this cookie value want to use in jquery file

```
var loggedUserId = $.cookie('LoggedUserId');
```

but it is returning undefined.

I also tried this..

```
var loggedUserId = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LoggedUserId"].Value';
```

But it is returning `@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LoggedUserId"].Value` as a `string` in `loggedUserId`.

Please suggest me to move forward. Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the cookies for the domain and make sure the server is actually setting it?

Comment: also check the expiration time for cookie

Comment: Can you show code that actually sets cookie (not creating `HttpCookie` object, but setting on the response)? And also consider showing list of .js files you include (as `$.cookie` is not part of `jQuery`).

Comment: Are you by any chance setting `cookie.HttpOnly` to `true`? Debug your app and make sure this is set to false.

Answer (score 2):

If you are putting your code on page then your code will run perfectly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var cookie = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["mycookie"].Value';
   alert(cookie);
</script>
```

But in case, you are adding your code in js file then this code might do your work.

```
function getCookieValue(name) {
    cookieList = document.cookie.split('; ');
    cookies = {};
    for (i = cookieList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cookie = cookieList[i].split('=');
        cookies[cookie[0]] = cookie[1];
    }
    return cookies[name];
}
```

Please see this link for more detail. Hope it can help you.

http://dotnet-concept.com/Article/2014/12/34/Create-Update-and-Get-cookie-value-through-javascript